# Track and log/debug yarn apllication which have been started from a scala binary using spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, debugging, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to design an integration testing framework.
I will be running some jars, which are written in Scala and run Spark processes with `spark-submit --master yarn` command. 
Is there any way that while running this jar I can submit some id or some name which will help me find which yarn process was called by which jar so that it becomes easier to debug?

Edit: I can't edit the code in scala, the only thing I can do it run the jars in my environment.

Comment: You can also provide application name using "--conf spark.app.name=spark-pi" parameter in your spark-submit command, once spark is submitted you can track the application as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the yarn application submitted by Spark using the application name.

a. submit Spark application using application name parameter.

```
SparkSession.builder.appName("spark-app-name")......
```

b. Check the Yarn application id using the appname.

```
yarn application -list | awk '$2 == "spark-app-name" {print $1}'
```

c. Once you get the application id, you can check the status of the Yarn application by using Yarn REST API:

```
http://<RM_HOST>:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/$job_id/state
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `spark-submit` option `--name [spark_job_name]` to name your spark_job and easily identify him afterwards.